# Filtering out duplicate dates from different nodes in views

Tags: 7, views

I have a "This day in history" page on my website, which when viewed in a monthly view shows of list of everything that has happened on each day in the month (so, for example January might say January 1: Monkeys learn to motorbike, January 2: Otters invade, etc.)

My issue is we have some new historical dates we want to add, so in this view I'm starting to see duplicate dates that have different content. (i.e, January 10: Yeti discovered, January 10: Moose have picnic with Bears).

The problem is I don't want to have duplicate dates on this view, rather I only want the most recently published/updated node to show up. Is there a way I can order a unique based off of a date field in views?

I'm sure I could probably do this through a views template and just manually remove the duplicate dates, but I would rather just limit the amount of data I'm receiving in the first place.

I'm wondering if this could be done through aggregation? Group my responses together based on their date, and only allow one item per group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was a way to do this purely in [views](http://www.drupal.org/projects/views), I haven't discovered it.

What I was able to do though, was to use templates to remove the second item if it had a date that matched another item.